# Store Parse Pointer value in variable

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as the backend for my app. In the User Class I have a pointer to an Album Class. I am trying to store that Album pointer value in a variable. I've tried declaring the variable as a PFObject, but I get the following error:

> unrecognized selector sent to class

Code looks like this

This variable is declared above the class so it's available globally

```
var album = PFObject()

func getUserInfo() {

        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

        let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")

        userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
        userQuery.includeKey("album")

        userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for result in results! {
                        album = result["album"] as PFObject
                }

            }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What line of code is causing that error to be thrown? When you fetch your user are you calling `includeKey("Album")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the problem vanish if you declare your album as an album?:

```
var album = PFObject(className:"Album")
```

I think it's failing because it's trying to assign data coming in from the query to a plain old `PFObject` that lacks the right fields to hold the data.

Comment: WooHoo...that solved it! Makes sense to me now. I'll learn this stuff some day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome! (BTW, did you know "You're welcome!" seems to be the shortest thing you can type in a comment reply box?)

Comment: Good to know. Hopefully I'll be answering questions instead of asking them sometime soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch your user are you calling includeKey("Album")?